# What does なあって mean here?

Tags: colloquial-language, sentence, anime, sentence-final-particles

I'm trying to figure out what is the significance of なあって in the following sentence:

> そのままからかいやすい西片でいてほしい**なあって**

It feels like it is there for emphasis or something but I just don't get where it comes from as no dictionary or web search I made could find the source, is it なー+って? Is it a contraction of something? Is it なんって?

All I managed to find are some sentence on [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%AA%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22) that use it but I'm unable to deduce its meaning and composition from them:
[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The examples pairing it with 思う seem to make it pretty clear that it is なー+って in those. Are you sure you posted the entire sentence (from, I assume, からかい上手の高木さん)?

Comment: I'm sure this is the entire sentence, the lines before and after belong to Nishikata. I don't see how the examples with 思う makes it obvious, but even so what does なー (which from what I can gather means "hey")  and って (which is for quotation and should probably be followed by an omitted 思う) mean together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なあって is not a contraction of any specific words.

- なあ is the same as な, the sentence-end particle. It has several functions, but in this case, it's simply "oh" or "really".
- って is basically an informal quotative particle. You can imagine something like (私は)思う has been omitted, like the examples on Weblio. Sentence-end って has several functions, too, but in this case, it is used to soften the sentence. Adding this って has an similar effect to adding "maybe", "kinda", "you know" or "I guess".

So the なあ part has the effect of intensifying his wish, while the って is used to express his hesitation/modesty.

> そのまま、からかいやすい西片でいてほしいなあって。
>
> I really wish you'd stay the same, easy-to-tease Nishikata, you know.

Answer (score 1):

なあ, like ねえ, is a particle used to soften a statement and invite confirmation, but having a somewhat rougher, rustic, flavour about it, な・なあ particularly being used when talking to oneself; and って is another form of と. If there is no verb after と・って, you can assume a verb of saying, or thinking, such as 言って, 思って etc. has been omitted.

Coming at the end of a sentence as in your extract, it is more likely to be taken as an abbreviation of といって[ください] (compare いいって said by someone pouring a dring, 'say when [it is enough]'), but that doesn't appear to make much sense here. More context is need to be able to give a proper translation.